# Div position absolute?

Tags: html, css

is there a possibility to get it with css as shown on the picture ?
first = black
second = blue
the HTML structure is like this (and must not be changed)

```
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->




<!-- end snippet -->
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbQiG.png)

I have already tried a few things, for example with postion absolute, but the blue div containers are only on top of each other

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox but your container has to have a height and you need a spacer element.

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
.container div {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
}

.container .spacer {
  flex: 1;
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
  
  <div class="spacer"></div>

  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The spacer isn't actually needed. You could just put `margin-top: auto` on the first `.second` div.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can‘t change the HTML